# Merging issue with git pull origin production to a branch

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a branch image_carousel with all the changes. I have executed `git pull origin production` command inside image_carousel branch. But after executing the `git pull origin production` command only the production code is there all the local changes are gone.
Why?
How do i keep the local code as well ?

Answer (score 0):

Pull will always checkout a different branch, and if you committed all your changes, those are not part of the other branch.

If you want to integrate another branch in your current one, you can use `git merge <branch name>` or `git rebase <branch name>` depending on your projects defaults.

In the case of merge, it will fetch the changes and integrate them with an own merge commit. Where as rebase tries to put all the changes within your branch (each commit etc) on top of the base.

See https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing for a more concise discussion and explanation about rebasing vs merging.